# Get indexPathsForVisibleItems() not including ones under a translucent navigation bar

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, orientation-changes

I am developing an app targeting iOS 8.0+ using Swift 2.2. I have a `UICollectionView` which displays a different number of columns depending on the device orientation. In `viewWillTransitionToSize`, I use `indexPathsForVisibleItems()` and find the smallest index path to determine the first visible item and scroll to that item on orientation change.

This works well except that `indexPathsForVisibleItems()` includes items which are under the translucent navigation bar so the scrolling may be off by a few cells. Is there some way to know which cells are visible and not under the navigation bar?

Comment: You could note how tall the navigation bar is and the get the cell at that CGPoint in the UICollectionView.  Then you can scroll that cell to the top.

Comment: @Putz1103 Ah, thank you, I missed `indexPathForItemAtPoint`. Do you want to write up an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to scroll to a specific cell on rotation you could get the physical location of that cell on screen (take the height of your translucent navigation bar and the y coordinate of the cell) and call `indexPathForItemAtPoint`.  That will give you the first cell that is actually visible (not under the overlay).  Then you can tell the `UICollectionView` to scroll to that cell on rotation.